# Google Contacts API get all contact details (php)

Tags: php, google-api, google-contacts-api

I'm using the Google Contacts API and I'm able to extract names and email addresses , phone number , image but I'd like to also get contact address , note and also how to extract email as work or home

I'm using PHP and here's my code while authenticating:

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXml($xmlresponse);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);
$xpath->registerNamespace('atom', 'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom');
$xpath->registerNamespace('gd', 'http://schemas.google.com/g/2005');

foreach ($xpath->evaluate('/atom:feed/atom:entry') as $entry) {
  $contact = [
    'name' => $xpath->evaluate('string(atom:title)', $entry),
    'image' => $xpath->evaluate('string(atom:link[@rel="http://schemas.google.com/contacts/2008/rel#photo"]/@href)', $entry),
    'emails' => [],
    'numbers' => [],
    'conatctaddress' => []
  ];
  foreach ($xpath->evaluate('gd:email', $entry) as $email) {
    $contact['emails'][] = $email->getAttribute('address');
  }
  foreach ($xpath->evaluate('gd:phoneNumber', $entry) as $number) {
    $contact['numbers'][] = trim($number->textContent);
  }

}
```

how to fetch contact address . they(google api) mentioned formattedAddress , structuredPostalAddress but dont how to fetch and also find if it is home or work

**EDIT**

As mentioned in below answer i m getting xml response but that response is not complete. because contact details also contain birth date,anniversary,website details so this details are not fetch via

`https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?&oauth_token=abcdferyyrfyfyt` and also the remaining data i m getting is as

`<gd:organization rel='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#other'><gd:orgName>comright</gd:orgName><gd:orgTitle>software developer</gd:orgTitle></gd:organization>` 
so for this when i tried `foreach loop` as same for email i m getting `orgName` and `orgTitle` in one variable

Answer (score 0):

You can Use the GET method to the url endpoint "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/{userEmail}/full" to retrieve the contacts from google. You can also go through the [link](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/).It will help you.

Comment: using above url as `https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?&oauth_token=1234567894` i m getting xml response but it does not fetch complete response . for e.g. i m not able to get <gContact:website>